# sqlite database sorting

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting

I know this goes against conventional database techniques but what I want to do is sort a database by time in milliseconds as things are entered into them having the item with the lowest milliseconds first and longest last.

Is there an easy way to do this? I do realize this is going to be very resource hungry but the database acts as a sort of calendar and this would prevent from having 30 alarmManagers running.

opinions/suggestions?

Comment: Ohm, you can't sort a database table. It is unsorted. I don't really understand why you need this, could you explain further?

Comment: basically what I was thinking is with the database sorted the first item in the table would be the current alarm running. when that one gets triggered the next one gets set and so on and so forth. this way I dont have a bunch of alarm managers running since different events will be entered to go off at different times (ie. one in an hour, one in a week, one every day, one every year etc)

Comment: Then sort it by time like @Nikola answered, should be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do when you fetch the data using `ORDER BY`

For example:

`SELECT * FROM timetable ORDER BY somethingwithtime;`

Regardless they are not sorted in your database, the query will output data sorted.